# Which options can I change in groupingGroupBy function of jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

As I saw in [jqgrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping) 'groupingGroupBy' has two parameters: 'name' and 'options'. What is 'option' and can i change groupingView parameters like groupSummery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine the source code of `groupingGroupBy` method you will find [the only line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.grouping.js#L363) where the `options` parameter will be used:

```js
$t.p.groupingView = $.extend($t.p.groupingView, options || {});
```

So one can use `options` parameter to change properties of the `groupingView` parameter of jqGrid. [The documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agrouping#methods) of `groupingGroupBy` method gives you the same information.

> Perform a grouping by given name. A set of additional options can be
>   set with the option parameter. The groupingView object is extended
>   with the options parameter.

It's important to understand that [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) function **merge** the contents of existing properties of `groupingView` parameter with `options`. So if you changes for example `groupField` property and you specified `groupText` properties before then both the properties will be in the new  settings. Don't forget to change all properties which depends from each other.

Comment: i use $("#item-result-table").jqGrid('groupingGroupBy',{groupField : g , groupDataSorted : true, groupSummary : [true]}); what is wrong with this code?

Comment: @user1905897: Which value has `g` variable which you use for `groupField`? Where is **the first** (`name`) parameter of `groupingGroupBy`? The value of the first parameter of `groupingGroupBy` can be either a string or array of strings by which you want to do grouping.